# Rails sort created_at since X days ago with a simple dropdown

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Is there a correct way to let a user to sort records with a dropdown and select for example : Sort records created since 7 days / 30 days / 90 days?
There will be no more than 3 or 4 choices

Instead of using something like:

```
    @post = Post.where(created_at: 5.days.ago..Time.now)
```

Which don't let the user to choice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about a simple params that decide the amount of days to list?

```
# some controller

def action
  number_of = ([7, 30, 90].include?(params[:days].to_i) ? params[:days].to_i : 7)
  @post = Post.where(created_at: number_of.days.ago..Time.now)
end
```

and a naive erb template could be of the likes:

```
<%= form_tag "/controller/action", method: :get do %>
  <%= select_tag(:days, options_for_select([['7 days ago', 7], ['30 days ago', 30], ['90 days ago', 90])) %>
  <%= submit_tag("Filter") %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Not bad! But, how can I display that in the view as a dropdown?

Comment: only one comment - maybe you need to use Time.zone.now. Or raw SQL "DATE(created_at) between date(a) and date(b)"

Comment: It work! With 2 - 3 adjustments to make it work 100% on my app, and it will be good! I mark as an answer! Thank you again ;-)